# pseudocode Input, Processing, Output

Tags: pseudocode

> You will need to design an application that will prompt a user for a number between 1 and 12. After getting the input, display the number with the appropriate month. (example: This is the 1st month…January, This is the 2nd month…February, This is the 12th month…December). You may just fill in this document with the correct answers.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know what to put in the Processing part or the Output.

> Pseudocode: This is where you code the exact instructions to do the processing part of the IPO chart and what you need to do to produce the output.

```
Input number of month

IF MONTH = 1 THEN
    DISPLAY “January”
END IF

IF MONTH = 2 THEN
    DISPLAY “February”
END IF

IF MONTH = 3 THEN
    DISPLAY “March”
END IF

IF MONTH = 4 THEN
    DISPLAY “April”
END IF

IF MONTH = 5 THEN
    DISPLAY “May”
END IF

IF MONTH = 6 THEN
    DISPLAY “June”
END IF

IF MONTH = 7 THEN
    DISPLAY “July”
END IF

IF MONTH = 8 THEN
    DISPLAY “August”
END IF

IF MONTH = 9 THEN
    DISPLAY “September”
END IF

IF MONTH = 10 THEN
    DISPLAY “October”
END IF

IF MONTH = 11 THEN
    DISPLAY “November”
END IF

IF MONTH = 12 THEN
    DISPLAY “December”
END IF

End

Processing

Output
```

Comment: The Guy with The Hat, any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

> Variables: MONTH_NUMBER, MONTH_NAME
>
> Input:
>
> ```
>    READ(MONTH_NUMBER)
> ```
>
> Processing:
>
> ```
>    IF  MONTH_NUMBER = 1  THEN:
>         MONTH_NAME = "January"
>          .
>          .
>          .
>    IF  MONTH_NUMBER = 12  THEN:
>         MONTH_NAME = "December"
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
>    PRINT(MONTH_NAME)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Prompt Month_num
2) GET Month_num
3) Set Msg = ‘null’
4) Month_name
  IF (month_num ==1) then
  Month_name = ‘Jan’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num ==2) then
      Msg = ‘Feb’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num ==3) then
      Msg = ‘Mar’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num ==4) then
      Msg = ‘Apr’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num ==5) then
      Msg = ‘May’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num ==6) then
      Msg = ‘June’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num ==7) then
      Msg = ‘July’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num ==8) then
      Msg = ‘Aug’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num ==9) then
      Msg = ‘Sept’
      ELSE
      IF (month_num ==10) then
      Msg = ‘Oct’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num ==11) then
      Msg = ‘Nov’
    ELSE
      IF (month_num =12) then
      Msg = ‘Dec’
    ELSE
      MSG = “Invalid entry”
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
END.
```

Or

```
CASEOF Month_num
'1' : Print 'Jan'
'2' : Print 'Feb'
so on so forth
other : Print 'invalid month'
ENDCASE
END.
```